# Android gmail login in version 6.0.1 not able to retrieve accounts.

Tags: android, gmail

I am not able to retrieve gmail account and its detail in 6.0.1 android phone version. Please suggest some code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add some code what you have try

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html

Comment: I have used this link for gmail login     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275022/android-gmail-login-in-version-6-0-1-not-able-to-retrieve-accounts

Comment: Update the Google play lib

Comment: What are u using gradle dependency or Google play lib project